# Max number of connections (Debian, phpmyadmin, apache)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, debian, vps

I just got an online game live, and everything when great until about 2000 players decided to play at the same time. Now everything runs really slow when getting data from the server. I have about 500 queries / second. I have a VPS with debian, and using phpmyadmin.

I did some searches, and one solution that sounds reasonable is that I don't have enough "max connections".

How can I check how many connections I have right now, and how can I increase it?

Many thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html. However, if your game is already running slow.. allowing more people to access it isn't going to increase performance. That's like having too many people to fit through a door.. then solving it by adding more people to push harder.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found the max_connections.. How do I increase it? Can I do it from within phpmyadmin? Do I need to restart the server? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

edit php.ini max_connections , to allow more connections to mysql .. you should also check what is eating up your connections and resources..
also you could consider cache or upgrade of vps ram..